# ADF Data flow expression

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, data-transform

I am trying to build ADF data flow select operation to dynamically select column names.
I am receiving required column names in an array parameter named 'colNames' and then I am trying to use that in data flow expression to check if column name in the schema matching any of required column names in an array, then only use that. But its not working , its not selecting any of columns .

```
contains($colNames,#item==name)
```

looks like the inbuilt expression 'name' is not the same as that I am trying to use in contains method

[image]

Comment: What does "not working" mean? (I honestly write this multiple times a day on here)

Comment: Could you please provide columnNames parameter values?

Answer (score 0):

In a SELECT activity expression, *$$* refers to the column name, so use that in your contains statement:

```
contains($colName,$$)
```